# How to get text parts of wikipedia and use it at my android application

Tags: android, popup, wikipedia, mapactivity

I wrote an app that displays my location in a popup on a map, and also other locations from a database. I want to get some information from Wikipedia and present portions of it as location information.

But, I have no idea how to do this. I am new at Android, and I hope I can find some answers here.

Comment: have you tried at least something? -> whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1):

You could use this [Wikilocation API](http://wikilocation.org/).  It uses your current location to bring up nearby articles.  Here is a sample:

```
http://api.wikilocation.org/articles?lat=51.500688&lng=-0.124411&limit=1
```

Will return

```
{
    "articles": [
        {
            "id": "7290308",
            "lat": "51.5006",
            "lng": "-0.124611",
            "title": "Big Ben",
            "url": "http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/w\/index.php?curid=7290308",
            "distance": "17m"
        }
    ]
}
```

Showing you that you are nearby Big Ben.  See [here](http://wikilocation.org/documentation/) for more docs

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the user to the wikipedia mobile page if you use this as your search term:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + search
```

or if you don't want to display it in a WebView or in the browser, you could use the [Wikimedia API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page) to display only relevant parts of the description.